# Spring Boot API response time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am developing the Spring Boot API's.

Now comes the monitoring part. I want to add monitoring to it. So I used actuator, fetch data(like gc, memory etc) from it & plot it on Grafana.

Now comes the response time of API's. Actuator guage just return the last API Hit. So basically how do I calculate the response time of every API for evry hit. I mean where I should place

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and

```
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long diff = endTime - startTime;
```

I have tried placing it on controller, 1st line of controller & last line of controller but the result is different when I am comparing it with Guage.

How should I correctly measure it?

Comment: what you are looking for is a histogram, Spring boot acuator doesn't have support for histogram, But Spring Boot Actuator can work with Dropwizard's metrics library(http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.2.2/), which has histogram support, check it out.

Comment: What I am more curious abt that is there any way I can get that data manuyally? Response time with every API Hit?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and have an AOP "around" advice around the `DispatcherServlet#service` method maybe?

Untested:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AroundExample {

    @Around("org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.service()")
    public Object doBasicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        // start stopwatch
        Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
        // stop stopwatch
        return retVal;
    }

}
```

Don't forget to add the `aop` starter in your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

That would give you a pretty close timing of the whole request invocation, including all the stuff like Spring interceptors, handlers, controllers, etc.

Comment: public class XYZ {
  
    @Around("execution(* org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.service(..))")
     public Object doBasicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
         // start stopwatch
      System.out.println("Before");
         Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
         // stop stopwatch
         System.out.println("Me here");
         return retVal;
     }
  
}
This code is executing but not printing anything? What Am i Missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "executing, but not printing anything"? Did you set a breakpoint in the debugger?

Comment: I mean no compile errors are there but still even i after i place prints, nothing is printed. I mean code is compiling but not printing anything